# What are "prefields" really called, and where can I learn more about them?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, terminology

By a *prefield*, I mean a commutative ring $R$ such that for all non-zero $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, the image of $n$ under the unique ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow R$ is a unit. In other words, its a commutative ring $R$ for which there exists a homomorphism $\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow R$.

> **Question.** What are prefields really called, and where can I learn more about them?

Every prefield has characteristic either $1$ or $0$, and only the trivial prefield has characteristic $1$. Nevertheless, prefields form a well-behaved concrete category, because there exists a Lawvere theory whose models in $\mathbf{Set}$ are precisely the prefields; just take the Lawvere theory of commutative rings and adjoin a constant symbol for each element of $\mathbb{Q}$, then quotient out by the equations of $\mathbb{Q}$. The initial object of this category is $\mathbb{Q}$. More generally, the free prefield on a set $X$ consists of polynomials with rational coefficients and indeterminates in $X$.

The cool thing about prefields is that there's a better alternative to the usual monomial basis for polynomials. For example, if $P$ is a non-trivial prefield, then $P[x]$ has basis $\{x^n/n! \mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}.$ This makes differentiation into the shift operator. For example:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(a_2\frac{x^2}{2}+a_1 x + a_0) = a_2 x + a_1$$

So in this basis, differentiation just shifts all the coefficients over. The same trick can be applied to formal power series with coefficients in $P$.

Comment: Sometimes called just a commutative ring over the rationals.

Comment: Do you mean commutative *unital* ring?

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas, my rings are unital by definition, and my semirings have both a $0$ and a $1$, also by definition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rings $R$ for which there is a ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Q}\to R$ (which is necessarily unique) are precisely the $\mathbb{Q}$-algebras.

Comment: Good point! $\;\!$ Note that the question also asks where I can learn more about them, specifically.

Comment: @goblin: I'm not sure if there's anything specific to say about them - it's not the sort of structure I'd expect there to be an separate account of. Basically the place to learn about them would be a section on algebras over a field in any given commutative algebra book.

Comment: Right, good thinking. "Algebras over fields" sounds like a good lead. Or better yes, "algebras over fields of characteristic $0$." Note that we need characteristic $0$ for the basis $\{x^n/n! \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ to even make sense.

Comment: @goblin: If your main interest is about working with $\frac{x^n}{n!}$, then you should take a look at divided power algebras ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_power_structure)) which do not require characteristic $0$.

Comment: Woah, cool... $\;\!$